# Analyse content of vector position

Tags: c

I need to compare if all the numbers on the vector are equal to zero. If its not, print a message.

I was thinking of pointing to the content of the address, but how can I do that?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int linha_user=0, coluna_user=0;
    float *identidade[linha_user][coluna_user];
    int linha, coluna;
    int se=0,sim=0,nao=0;
    printf("Digite o número de linhas desejado na matriz:\n");
    scanf("%d", &linha_user);
    printf("Digite o número de colunas desejado na matriz:\n");
    scanf("%d", &coluna_user);

    for (linha=0;linha<linha_user;linha++)
    {
        for (coluna=0;coluna<coluna_user;coluna++)
        {
            printf("Digite o número desejado para a posição %d,%d\n",linha,coluna);
            scanf("%d", &identidade[linha][coluna]);
        }
    }

    for (linha=0;linha<linha_user;linha++)
    {
        for (coluna=0;coluna<coluna_user;coluna++)
        {
            if (*identidade[linha][coluna] != 0)
            {
                se=nao;
            }
            else
            {
                se=sim;
            }
        }
    }

    if (se == nao)
    {
        printf("Nem todos os elementos são iguais a zero\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Todos os elementos são iguais a zero.\n");
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, is it Spanish?

Comment: Portuguese... I'm from Brazil.. :)

Comment: Ok, I will know next time. =)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not likely to help other people in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Please use English in comments, messages, and identifier names.

I reindented your code with GNU `indent`, then I compiled it (using GCC 4.8) with `gcc -Wall -Wextra` and got

```
walter.c: In function 'main':
walter.c:22:4: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'float **' [-Wformat=]
scanf ("%d", &identidade[linha][coluna]);
^
walter.c:49:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

}

And your declaration

```
 int linha_user=0, coluna_user=0;
 float *identidade[linha_user][coluna_user];
```

is certainly wrong. You are declaring a zero sized matrix of float pointers (that won't change if later you set `linha_user` or `coluna_user` with a.g. `scanf` or some assignment).

I strongly recommend reading some good C programming book.

You probably want (at least on Linux) to debug your program with a debugger (like `gdb` on Linux) and a memory leak detector (like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on Linux).

BTW, the *vector* terminology you are using makes me suggest using [C++2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (with the GCC 4.8 compiler) and its container classes, notably its [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) standard template. Of course you want to compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g` in that case.

Comment: These days, the question could be asked on the Portugese site.

Answer (score 1):

Your two objects `sim` and `nao` have the same value of `0` in your program. They need to have different values (like `0` and `1`) if you want to distinguish them in:

```
if (se == nao)
```

Then you when you observe a non zero element you need to `break` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Is it possible to `break` from 2 loops?

Comment: @Alex you need a `break` in the first loop, then a test condition and a `break` in the second loop. Or a `goto` with a label after the two loops.

Comment: I personally, would choose `goto`

Comment: The other way to break from N loops is an early return from a function. But that would need the loops to be inside a separate function, and not in main (which is a good idea anyway)